# Is there any PHP function to make an array if we have a string and array length?

Tags: php, arrays

Is there any PHP function to make an array if we have a string and know array count?

example:

```
$sample = 'required|numeric|between:0,99.99';
$count = 3;


$validation_arr = ['required|numeric|between:0,99.99','required|numeric|between:0,99.99','required|numeric|between:0,99.99'];
```

Comment: `$validation_arr = array_fill(0,  $count, $sample)`

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a predefined array function namely as `array_fill` which is used to fill given array keys. Below is the example of `array_fill` and an answer to your question.

```
    $count = 3;
    $a = array_fill(0,$count, 'required|numeric|between:0,99.99');
    print_r($a);
    //Output Array
    (
       [0] => required|numeric|between:0,99.99
       [1] => required|numeric|between:0,99.99
       [2] => required|numeric|between:0,99.99
    )
```